# Chosen maximal subject is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

Let $ G $ is a finite soluble group and $ N $ be a unique minimal normal subgroup of $ G $. Let $ G = TS $ that $ S $ is the fitting subgroup of $ G $ and $ T = N_{G}(H) $ for $ H \leq G $. Suppose $ T \cap N = 1 $. Let $ U $ be chosen maximal subject to $ T \leq U $ and $ U \cap N = 1 $.  Why $ U < G $ ?

Comment: This doesn't make sense. You have $T \cap N = 1$ twice. Presumably you want some condition on $U$, not on $T$?

Comment: Excuse me. Today I am confused. $ U \cap N = 1 $.

Comment: But then it's obvious that $U < G$.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: What do you mean by "subject" as in "maximal subject"?

Comment: I presume by $U < G$ you mean $U$ is a subgroup of $G$ but $U \ne G$? But if $U \cap N = 1$ then clearly $U \ne G$.

Comment: @CameronBuie A "minimal normal subgroup" of a group is defined to be a normal subgroup that is not itself equal to the identity, but does not properly contain any other normal subgroups not equal to the identity.

Comment: @Derek: Thank you for clarifying that for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that what you're saying is that $U$ is supposed to be a subgroup of $G$ that is maximal with respect to the following property:

> $T\le U$ and $U\cap N=1.$

If we had $U=G,$ then we would have $U\cap N=N\ne 1,$ so clearly we can't have $U=G.$ Moreover, since (it seems) you're requiring that $U\leq G,$ then we have $U<G.$

Observe that this has *nothing* to do with the properties of $G,$ nor with $S,T,$ or $H.$ We don't even need $N$ to be unique! It seems that we can rephrase as follows:

> If $G$ is **any** group, $N$ **any** minimal normal subgroup of $G,$ $T$ **any** subgroup of $G$ such that $T\cap N=1,$ and $U$ is a subgroup of $G$ that is maximal with respect to the conditions $T\subseteq U$ and $U\cap N=1,$ then $U<G.$